# Forcing UITabView to 'dock' or lock to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uitabbar

I'm SUPER new to mac and Objective C. Interface builder is also new. I'm trying to get a UITabBar with three UITabBarItems to freeze, or dock, or stay at the bottom of the screen. I've tried a few different things in IB, but no luck... any pointers?
[image: Screen Shot] Notice the big white gap at the bottom.

Thank you,

Comment: I've had the exact same problem before, is the tab bar added as a subview?

Comment: I stuck it on a NIB file that is added as a subview, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just starting, the easiest way to do this -- by far -- is to simply select the [**Tab Bar Application template**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/100-iOS_Development_Quick_Start/development_quick_start.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH3-SW24) when you create your project.

The UITabBar needs to belong to the window (for learning's sake), not stuck in one of your views. In your AppDelegate the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is where subviews are added to your window. If you use the template I mentioned, the end of this method looks like this:

```
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

instead of having your viewController added. The views that are attached to each tab are associated with the tab bar in Interface Builder (again, for learning's sake).